# functions that work with mingw don't work with vc++.NET

Tags: string, mingw, textinput, visual-c++

I have a very simple program

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
string something;
cout << "Enter Something:" << endl;
cin >> something;
return 0;
}
```

this does gives me the error of

> ThePath: error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
>   whats wrong did I not download the platform sdk right

or is this a little bug in the msdn library

I have also figured out that this:    `getline(cin, SomeString, '\n');` gives me this error

> ThePath : error C3861: 'getline': identifier not found

the simple question is why?

why is this happening?

thanks

### Luck

Comment: How this programm is supposed to work? What happens?

Comment: If something "doesn't work", say what error you get and where you get it. "doesn't work" is never a good error description...

Comment: I completly forgot the namespace, sorry  but its up now and my problem is not with the functions it's with the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably need to include string in the header

```
#include <string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to names from the `std` namespace (like `string` or `cin`) without qualifying the names with `std::`. For the names to be found you should use `std::string` and `std::cin` etc.

Comment: thanks for the quick response but I relized that I forgot the namespace, it is up now, and what is up on my answer is the final ... an added namespace as well as my error messages